# fingerprintjs2 Uncaught ReferenceError: murmur is not defined at

Tags: javascript, fingerprintjs2

the code doesn't work like this for me to work this way

how do I run code like below

```html
<script src="https://www.mobilcet.com/deneme/fingerprint2.js"></script>
        <script> Fingerprint2.get(function(components) { 
var murmur = Fingerprint2.x64hash128(components.map(function (pair) { return pair.value }).join(), 31) }) 
document.write(murmur); 
    </script>
```

Comment: I want to manage the code this way